# Alias Gateway ePDQ Hosted Payment Page Barclaycard

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, payment, payment-method

I'm trying to save card details on the server side using Barclaycard Alias Gateway but its not saving card details and not making any Alias on the server side. here is my code to send make request alias in the server side

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

// Define the Alias Gateway URL
$alias_gateway_url = 'https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard_utf8.asp';

// Define request parameters as an associative array
$request_params = [
    'PSPID' => 'xxxxx',
    'ORDERID' => '5454545d55585858856568',
    'USERID' => 'xxxx',
    'AMOUNT' => '1000',
    'CURRENCY' => 'GBP',
    'LANGUAGE' => 'en_US',
    'ALIAS' => 'A1678109291015',
    'ECI' => '9',
    'OPERATION' => 'RES',
    'SHASIGN' => 'DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709',
    'PAIDAMOUNT' => '50',
    'SHASOUT' => 'wheMdKu%2F5Li%3FfR%2BFV18',
    'PSWD' => 'xxxxx',
    'SHA-IN' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
];

// Convert request parameters to query string
$query_string = http_build_query($request_params);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $alias_gateway_url . '?' . $query_string,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('soft_key' => 'dUjZaHmtjLvA4N0O8k1ddym6', 'soft_email' => 'maxcdd@gmail.com'),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Cookie: sessionTest=1f39eaf2-6f3c-4c99-a3a1-f55994a99a37',
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

How to fix this and save Alias on server side on Barclaycard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.